# Geometry nodes not effecting after I reopened the save file

Tags: geometry-nodes, saving

I finished the geometry nodes part 1 from Blender Guru. I saved the file and the next day when I reopened the save, the nodes had no effect on the icing. I tried restarting the PC and restarting Blender, but nothing worked. I would like to know if anyone had the same experience and if someone knows how to fix it. [image: here is a scr of the blender file]

[image]

Comment: You can share your Blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link to it and then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you deleted somehow your geometry nodes modifier.

[image]

Just add it back to the icing.

You still "see" the GN node tree in that window only because you pinned it. That doesn't mean, that it is added to any object.

Comment: thank you SO much, Chris!